# How to draw a tikzpicture as a node?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, color, tikz-node

I want to draw something instead a node and thought that it is a good solution to solve this with `tikzset`. But it doesn't work. I read also

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\tikzset{statistic/.pic={
    \draw[line width=1] (0,2) -- (0,0) -- (2,0);
    \draw[line width=2,color=ProcessBlue] (0.4,0.1) -- (0.4,1);
    \draw[line width=2,color=ProcessBlue] (1,0.1) -- (1,1);
    \draw[line width=2,color=ProcessBlue] (1,0.1) -- (1,1.5);
    \draw[line width=2,color=ProcessBlue] (1.6,0.1) -- (1.6,1.9);
}}
```

And then I want to use it with this command:

```
\statistic at (0,0) {};
```

I read also that `\tikzset` is deprecated. So it would better to solve this with `\pgfplotsset` or?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are several different ways for usihg a `pic` including:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \pic at (0,0) {statistic};
  \draw (4,0) pic{statistic};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

which produces:

[image]

This said, if you want the `statistic` pic to be really useful you probably do not want to hard-wire the `x` and `y` coordinates. You could, instead, define `better statistic` to accept a comma separated list of `x` and `y` coordinates so that the code

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \pic at (0,0) {better statistic={0.4/1, 1/1, 1.6,1.9}};
  \draw (4,0) pic{better statistic={0.4/1, 1/1, 1.6,1.9, 2.1, 0.4, 2.4, 3.2}};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

produces

[image]

This is easy to do because a `pic` can accept an argument (in fact, using a slightly different syntax, it can take multiple arguments), so you can just loop over the coordinates in `#1` by defining

```
\tikzset{better statistic/.pic={
    \def\xmax{1.5}
    \def\ymax{1.5}
    \foreach \x/\y in {#1} {
      \draw[line width=2,color=blue] (\x,0.1) -- ++(0,\y);
      \pgfmathparse{max(\x,\xmax)}\xdef\xmax{\pgfmathresult}
      \pgfmathparse{max(\y,\ymax)}\xdef\ymax{\pgfmathresult}
    }
    \draw[line width=1] (0,\ymax+0.5) -- (0,0) -- (\xmax+0.5,0);
  }
}
```

The only slightly tricky bit is in choosing the maximum heights of the `x` and `y` axes. Depending on your data you might hard code these or choose them dyanmically as above.

Here is the full code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\tikzset{statistic/.pic={
    \draw[line width=1] (0,2) -- (0,0) -- (2,0);
    \draw[line width=2,color=blue] (0.4,0.1) -- (0.4,1);
    \draw[line width=2,color=blue] (1,0.1) -- (1,1);
    \draw[line width=2,color=blue] (1,0.1) -- (1,1.5);
    \draw[line width=2,color=blue] (1.6,0.1) -- (1.6,1.9);
  }
}


\tikzset{better statistic/.pic={
    \def\xmax{1.5}
    \def\ymax{1.5}
    \foreach \x/\y in {#1} {
      \draw[line width=2,color=blue] (\x,0.1) -- ++(0,\y);
      \pgfmathparse{max(\x,\xmax)}\xdef\xmax{\pgfmathresult}
      \pgfmathparse{max(\y,\ymax)}\xdef\ymax{\pgfmathresult}
    }
    \draw[line width=1] (0,\ymax+0.5) -- (0,0) -- (\xmax+0.5,0);
  }
}

\begin{document}

  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \pic at (0,0) {statistic};
    \draw (4,0) pic{statistic};
  \end{tikzpicture}

  \bigskip

  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \pic at (0,0) {better statistic={0.4/1, 1/1, 1.6,1.9}};
    \draw (4,0) pic{better statistic={0.4/1, 1/1, 1.6,1.9, 2.1, 0.4, 2.4, 3.2}};
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

ps Btw, `\tikzset` is the recommended command to use here. There is an older `\tikzstyle` command that has been depreciated.

**Edit**

To rescale these diagrams, as asked in the comments, there are two easy ways to do this:

Rescale the entire `tikzpicture` environment using:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]
  \pic at (0,0) {better statistic={0.4/1, 1/1, 1.6,1.9}};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Rescale an individual `pic` using:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \pic[scale=0.5] at (0,0) {better statistic={0.4/1, 1/1, 1.6,1.9}};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

You can also scale in just the `x` or `y` directions using `xscale` and `yscale`, respectively.

Comment: How could I scale the nodes?

Comment: @ikreb Which nodes do you want to scale and how?

Comment: For example``\pic at (0,0) {statistic};``.

Comment: I am still not sure what you mean by "scale". With the code above you can specify arbitrary `x` and `y` coordinates. What do you want to scale?

Comment: If I want to have the pic smaller. To resize the xmax/ymax is not enough.

Comment: @ikreb See my edit.

Comment: My train... is derailed ahahah.

Answer (score 6):

The other approach is to use `savebox`es.  I believe a `savebox` is implemented as low-level commands to the PDF driver, whereas a `pic` is implemented as low-level PGF commands (like `\pgfpathmoveto` and `\pgfpathlineto`).  Just guessing, though.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
%\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newsavebox{\tempbox}
\savebox\tempbox{\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[line width=1] (0,2) -- (0,0) -- (2,0);
    \draw[line width=2,color=ProcessBlue] (0.4,0.1) -- (0.4,1);
    \draw[line width=2,color=ProcessBlue] (1,0.1) -- (1,1);
    \draw[line width=2,color=ProcessBlue] (1,0.1) -- (1,1.5);
    \draw[line width=2,color=ProcessBlue] (1.6,0.1) -- (1.6,1.9);
\end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{document}
\usebox\tempbox
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[inner sep=0pt] {\usebox\tempbox};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```